# How to find the latest *compatible* version of a Pypi package?

Tags: python, pypi, python-3.2

On a production server, I am forced to use python3.2. Sadly several of my dependencies require `>=python3.4`. 
Is there a way to find out what the latest version of a package is that can be used with a specific python version?

For instance, with `python3.2`, what version of `numpy` should be used?

(This is only an example, answers would ideally not focus on the example, but on the actual question).

Comment: There rarely is a *good* technical reason for such an old Python version. You should really consider upgrading or a side by side installation. If that is not possible at all use Docker.

Comment: @KlausD. agreed, but I am using a managed service, I have no say in the python version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) to solve the problem?

These are strings that can be used in `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` files (under the `install_requires` argument) and look like:

```
numpy>=1.7,<2; python_version > '3.4'
numpy>=1.7,<1.12; python_version < '3.4'
```

They can help you match packages to Python versions with some flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

This should work with pip>=22.2 (tested with Python 3.10.8 + pip 22.2.2) and give you the latest version of a package compatible with a given Python version:

```
python -m pip install numpy --dry-run --python-version 3.2 --no-deps --target foo
```

Output:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.12.1.zip (4.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 4.8/4.8 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Would install numpy-1.12.1
```

Extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627014/how-to-know-what-python-version-a-package-is-compatible-with/74691613#74691613).

Answer (score -1):

You can go to individual package and check requirement. Like for Numpy you can check on [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py#L34) which tells `Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.`

Comment: That does not answer my question, it means I have to go through all the source code of all the packages to find the point in time when the requirements matched mine, and then select that specific release. Not a feasible option.