# How can I check what is the maximum python version that I can use with in my Django?

Tags: python, django, dependencies

I'm using Django with many pip modules; python version is 3.7.5.
I want to write a script that will tell me at any given moment what is the maximum python version that I can use without pip module changes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627014/how-to-know-what-python-version-a-package-is-compatible-with) information, you could know the Python version associated with your external packages in the "Meta" section of the Python Package Index.

There might be other better ways of achieving what you want, but here is what first comes to my mind: you could write a Python script that scans the list of packages from your requirements.txt, and later web scrapes the Python Package Index (using [beautiful soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)), and extracts the "Meta" information of each package that you are interested in.